# htaccess Dynamic Redirect that changes URL in clients browser

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect `/search.php?s=xxx` to `/search/xxx` and actually show /search/xxx in client's address bar.

I am using the following instruction in the htaccess root and it works **but doesn't change the URL**:

```
RewriteRule           ^search/(.*)$           /search.php?s=$1
```

I have tried adding [R=301] at the end of the statement, so:

```
RewriteRule           ^search/(.*)$           /search.php?s=$1 [R=301]
```

But this does the opposite, meaning it changes /search/xxx to /search.php?s=xxx

Here is the entire .htaccess file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule           ^monumentum$                  /new_monumentum.php
RewriteRule           ^monumentum/(.*)$             /new_monumentum.php?mid=$1

RewriteRule           ^nuntium$                     /new_articulo.php
RewriteRule           ^nuntium/(.*)$                  /new_articulo.php?aid=$1

RewriteRule           ^liber$                         /new_liber.php
RewriteRule           ^liber/(.*)$                  /new_liber.php?lid=$1

RewriteRule           ^introductio$               /new_pagina.php
RewriteRule           ^introductio/(.*)$            /new_pagina.php?pid=$1

RewriteRule           ^persona$               /new_profile.php
RewriteRule           ^persona/(.*)$          /new_profile.php?cid=$1

#RewriteRule          ^search$                /new_search.php
#RewriteRule          ^search/(.*)$           /new_search.php?sea=$1

RewriteRule           ^exitio$                /new_exit.php
RewriteRule           ^intro$                 /new_enter.php
RewriteRule           ^novus$                 /new_account.php

# Error 404: Paginas no encontradas
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Answer (score 1):

To redirect `/search.php?s=xxx` to `/search/xxx`, you may use this rule:

```sh
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search\.php\?s=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /search/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^search/(.+)$ search.php?s=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

# place your remaining rules below here

RewriteRule           ^monumentum$ new_monumentum.php [L]
RewriteRule           ^monumentum/(.*)$ new_monumentum.php?mid=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule           ^nuntium$ new_articulo.php [L]
RewriteRule           ^nuntium/(.*)$ new_articulo.php?aid=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule           ^liber$ new_liber.php [L]
RewriteRule           ^liber/(.*)$ new_liber.php?lid=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule           ^introductio$ new_pagina.php [L]
RewriteRule           ^introductio/(.*)$ new_pagina.php?pid=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule           ^persona$ new_profile.php [L]
RewriteRule           ^persona/(.*)$ new_profile.php?cid=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule           ^exitio$ new_exit.php [L]
RewriteRule           ^intro$ new_enter.php [L]
RewriteRule           ^novus$ new_account.php [L]

# Error 404: Paginas no encontradas
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but it still does not work. Same behaviour than my previous answer.

Comment: **My final comment on this answer** You wrote earlier everything is working fine except `/search/xxx`. With my latest update even that has been addressed.